# Why does Oracle SQL Developer freezes (unresponsive) once I create a new connection?

Tags: oracle-database, sqldeveloper

I have only installed Oracle XE (the latest version 18g) and SQL Developer.

Comment: Do you mean it freezes for a while and then you can keep working? Or that if freezes for an undefined time? What's the OS? Does that sit on Java? Are you choosing the JRE for it to sit? If so which one?

Comment: I happen to remember from Oracle SQL Developer 3 to 4 it sat on Java.

Comment: just a quick link in case this happens due to JDK (how to change the JDK sqldeveloper uses to run): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390562/oracle-sqldeveloper-jdk-path/24391298